# Chrome App Notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a function that displays a chrome notification from my app when an update is available. I typed it all up and it just doesn't work.

```
function updatenotification() {
chrome.notifications.create(memeNotification, {
    "type": "basic",
    "iconUrl":"icons/icon48.png",
    "title": "Update Available!",
    "message": "There is an update available for Meme Music Board!"
    });
};
```

Here is what I have. It is supposed to be triggered by the onUpdateAvailable api. However, no matter how I try to trigger the function it does NOT make a notification. I cannot even get any notifications to display. I have added the notifications permission to the manifest. I have tried it in my background.js as well as my main javascript. I am at my wits end. Any help would be wonderful. Thank you.

**Edit!**

I have also tried:

```
var options = {
    type : "basic",
    title: "Update Available",
    message: "An Update is available",
    expandedMessage: "An Update is available for Meme Music Board",
},

function notify() {
    chrome.notifications.create(options);
},
```

And for some reason it just does not work. This method works on other apps made by others.

Comment: When I type chrome.app. in the console, it doesn't give 'notifications' as  one of the keys contained in the app object.

Comment: `typeof chrome.notifications` is returning "undefined" for me

Comment: I'm trying to do this:https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-create

Comment: Perhaps this only works on a chromebook? On the following site: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications, there is mention of Chrome OS. Do you expect this to also work in the chrome browser?

Comment: I know that this works with extensions on windows.

Comment: Look at a [working sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/rich-notifications) and use the debugger to see what happens in your code. Also, try removing your app and re-add it.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is limited to the chromium browser? In my chrome browser Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)
 chrome.notifications.create does not seem to work because notifications is undefined.

Comment: What do you guys get? I just get a console error "main.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.getURL is not a function(…)"

Comment: I know the app works, as I have it now. But the method of creating the notification is different than the way I have seen other do it (That work)

Comment: perhaps you need a chrome web store plug-in referenced at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples . here is the link to the web store plug-in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notification-api-sample/cndmbddaappldijonoekcdfdlhemhejm

Comment: Well I settled on this: Using the app example provided and the information on the api. 
    var options = {
    type : "basic",
    title: "Update Available",
    message: "An Update is available",
    expandedMessage: "An Update is available for Meme Music Board",
},

function notify() {
    chrome.notifications.create(options);
   }
And it does not work.

Comment: @LexJacobs      I edited the post to show another method which I believe to be right but doesn't work as well.

Comment: I get undefined when typing "chrome.notifications" into the browser console. Do you get a different result? If not, then this api does not appear to be available on chrome browser without some extension.

Comment: @LexJacobs I don't know how to use the console like that. Also, Like i said. The example app uses the same method and the notifications on it work perfectly.

Comment: I get undefined as well. @LexJacobs But that console is for the browser no? I don't think it applies to the app